# Pass numeric value from one php file to another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 2 php files, the first file is the index file where the pagination is found, and an ajax script for getting the table data which is found on the second file.

The ajax script from the first file is also sending sorting option that the user requested to the second file. The second file will then sort and calculate the number of result that is found.

Since the pagination is in first file, I need the result from the second file to calculate the proper number of pages for my pagination.

I have this pagination script

```html
<ul class="pagination mx-1 mx-md-0">
    <?php 
        if(!empty($total_pages)){
            for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
                if($i == 1){
    ?>
        <li class="pageitem active" id="<?php echo $i;?>">
            <a href="JavaScript:Void(0);" data-id="<?php echo $i;?>" class="page-link" ><?php echo $i;?></a>
        </li>
            <?php 
                }
                else {
            ?>
        <li class="pageitem" id="<?php echo $i;?>">
            <a href="JavaScript:Void(0);" class="page-link" data-id="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
       </li>
       <?php
                }
            }
       }
       ?>
</ul>
```

I have this ajax script for my first file

```js
$("#target-content").load("pagination.php?page=1");
$(".page-link").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var sort = $("#myselect").val();
    var select_id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var categorytype = MyApp.categorytypes;
                            
    $.ajax({
        url: "secondfile.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            page : id,
            sorted:sort,
            categorytype:categorytype
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(dataResult){
            $("#target-content").html(dataResult);
            $(".pageitem").removeClass("active");
            $("#"+select_id).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

for my 2nd file I have this code

```php
<? php
    $limit= 2;
    $sqls = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM producttable $categorytypes ORDER BY $sortertype 
    $sorterorder LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqls);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_results);  
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit); 
?>
```

and to pass my data to the first file I tried creating another ajax script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var numb = <?php echo $total_pages ?>;
     $.ajax({
         url: "inde.php",
         type: "GET",
         data: {
             numb:numb
         }
     });
});
```

and tried to get the values in the first file using GET [] but it seems that it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong here? should I rewrite my whole code?

My displayed tables are going well, its just the number of pages that are shown when I'm sorting the data in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Drop that last code bit you showed and in your second .php file echo out the `total_pages` like this

```php
<? php
    $limit= 2;
    $sqls = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM producttable $categorytypes ORDER BY $sortertype 
    $sorterorder LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqls);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_results);  
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
    echo $total_pages;
?>
```

then in your ajax script, update your pagination using JS and you have your `$total_pages` passed through as `dataResult`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "secondfile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        page : id,
        sorted:sort,
        categorytype:categorytype
    },     
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataResult){
        // dataResult will contain $total_pages
        $("#target-content").html(dataResult);
        $(".pageitem").removeClass("active");
        $("#"+select_id).addClass("active");
        updatePagination(dataResult);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this sir but the $total_pages  in my first file is not being updated . and the $total_pages in my second file is only being displayed in my document

Comment: I have a code the computes the $total_pages in my first file but it is not passing the right value whenever i sort some items in my table since the number of items maybe reduced. thats why i want it to be overwritten by my $total_pages in my second file

Comment: Any reason you're using php instead of javascript in your index file to update?

Comment: the total_pages is first calculated in the index file, but it has no variables for sorting , it is just for the default number of pages for my pagination , the $total pages only changes when im sorting  the data in the 2nd file ,i dont know actually what to use to pass  the values from $total_pages in the 2nd file to my index file and update its $total_pages value.I tried using ajax in 2nd file but it seems to be not working well

Comment: Php is a server-side language, meaning as soon as your index page is rendered to the user all of its variables are destroyed. You're not going to be able to update any variables within index.php through ajax.

Comment: Yeah , I also realized that earlier , Im thinking of creating new php file for my pagination or re-creating my pagination code . Thank you sir!